# When I normalize the standardized values of data, why do I get the same values as just normalizing?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization, standardization

Please consider the following example:

[image]

In the second column, I standardize VAR1, subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. In the third column, I normalize VAR1 with the formula:

$$\frac{x - \min(x)}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$$

In the fourth column I normalize the standardized values of VAR1 (using the above mentioned formula, on column 2).

Can you tell me why columns 3 and 4 are the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The easy answer** is that standardization and normalization are linear transformations of the data and any line is determined by two distinct points on it.  Since columns 3 and 4 are constructed to include the points $(\min(\text{data}), 0)$ and $(\max(\text{data}), 1)$ (namely, $(2,0)$ and $(95, 1)$), they must result from identical transformations.

**The algebraically rigorous answer** manipulates the formulas.  Recall that **standardization** of data $\mathbf{x} = x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ replaces each $x_i$ with

$$y_i = \frac{x_i - \bar x}{s_x}$$

where $\bar x$ usually is the (arithmetic) mean of the data and $s_x$ often is a standard deviation of the data.  (Generally, $\bar x$ may be any estimate of a central value and $s_x$ may be any estimate of the spread, but such generality is usually not intended.)

On the other hand, **normalization** replaces each $x_i$ with

$$z_i = \frac{x_i - \min(\mathbf{x})}{\max(\mathbf x) - \min(\mathbf x)}.$$

But since $s_x \gt 0$, division by $s_x$ is an *increasing* function.  Subtracting any constant like $\bar x$ similarly is an increasing function. Therefore the extremes of $\mathbf x$ correspond to the extremes of $\mathbf y$.  Consequently, normalization of $\mathbf y = y_1, y_2, \ldots,y_n$ produces

$$\eqalign{
z_i^\prime &= \frac{y_i - \min(\mathbf{y})}{\max(\mathbf y) - \min(\mathbf y)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{x_i - \bar x}{s_x} - \min_j(\frac{x_j - \bar x}{s_x})}{\max_j(\frac{x_j - \bar x}{s_x}) - \min_j(\frac{x_j - \bar x}{s_x})} \\
&= \frac{{x_i - \bar x} - \min_j({x_j - \bar x})}{\max_j({x_j - \bar x}) - \min_j({x_j - \bar x})} \\
&= \frac{x_i - \min(\mathbf{x})}{\max(\mathbf x) - \min(\mathbf x)} \\
&= z_i.
}$$